# Use expanded today widget for 3D home screen?

Tags: ios, homescreen, today-extension

I have an expandable today widget by doing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
}

func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    preferredContentSize = activeDisplayMode == .expanded
        ? CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 200) : maxSize

    ...
}
```

The compact widget automatically shows for the 3D home screen touch. Is there a way to use the expanded view of the today widget besides creating a whole other today widget and specifying that as the home screen widget?

Comment: I don't think you can use an expanded version there at all.